# Injective Matrix Product State

Tags: tensor-networks

I am going through a [review on Tensor Networks](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1751-8121/aa6dc3/pdf) and came across these statements: [image: injective mps].

This was a bit quick for me.

I understand an injective MPS as one in which viewing $A$ as a map from auxiliary space to physical space, it is injective. This is a condition on a single tensor $A$.

Why does that imply that the transfer matrix $T = \sum_j A^{*}_j \otimes A_j$  has a **unique** left and right eigenvalue-1 eigenvector? Are the statements (i) injectivity on a single tensor and (ii) unique left right eigenvalue-1 eigenvectors of $T$, equivalent?

Now since there is a gauge degree of freedom in defining an MPS, I know we can put it in "left canonical form" which is defined by the RHS of 5.3. This thus determines the form of the dominant left eigenvector (if we believe in its uniqueness).

But why additionally is the right eigenvector (denoted by $\rho$), a "full-rank" density matrix?

Comment: Can you be more specific *which* points precisely you don't understand -- and which you do?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Thank you. I have edited my question to make it clearer, hopefully.

Comment: Much better now! This could serve as an example for what an edit to improve the post should do! -- I'll try to write sth. when I have time.